# Combine Likert Scale with accuracy of responses

Tags: spss, inference, descriptive-statistics, likert, scales

I am trying to transform my experiment results into variables and I am having some issues.

Data:

One likert scale 1-9 (

- 1 = " I am sure I havent seen this before”
- 5 = "Not sure”
- 9 = “I am sure I’ve seen this again”

So, I was measuring the certainty of the response.

However, the response had also a right or wrong answer, which affects the accuracy of the response.

Accuracy is 0 or 1 (0 = false, 1 = correct). Participants who answered 1-4 but actually saw the image before were labeled as wrong, and those 6-9 were labeled as right. The opposite for those images presented only the second time.

(I realised I shouldn’t be using a likert scale for this purpose, as its meant to be for opinions and not right/wrong responses).

Although I could only use the accuracy of response as my dependant variable, I was thinking that I should utilise the certainty as well. I am thinking about transforming my likert scale as :

1 = 4

2 = 3

3 = 2

4 = 1

5 = 0

6 = 1

7 = 2

8 = 3

9 = 4

And accuracy as:

0 = -1

1 = 1

Then multiply both variables to get my final accuracy with certainty, with a range of -4 to 4, using certainty as a weight.

Would this approach be a correct way of dealing with my example ?

Comment: You can try using https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/ with 3-class ordinal prediction problem and then using probabilities to evaluate the spread.

Answer (score 1):

You have initial responses $X$ taking integer values 1 through 9.

Then you have transformed 'certainty' scores $Y,$ defined as $Y = |X - 5|,$ taking values 0 through 4. 
I think these should be scores $Y = X - 5$ taking values
-4 through +4.

Then you should multiply by 1 or -1 to get scores $Z$ from -4 through 4, so that negative scores correspond to
various degrees of wrong answers and positive scores correspond to degrees
of correct answers. And finally, you would average these final scores $Z$ to
get the overall rating for a subject.

Let's see how this would work for three kinds of subjects, Clueless, (mainly)
Attentive, and (almost) Perfect. Specifically,

- Clueless subjects answer
  with an initial response 1 through 9, equally likely and at random;
- Attentive subjects assign initial scores 1 to 6 to images not seen before
  and scores 4 through 9 to images seen before (mainly correct or uncertain,
  occasionally wrong);
- Perfect subjects initially give 1 or 2 to images not
  seen before and 8 or 9 to the other images (always correct, but with slightly
  varying degrees of certainty).

In the simulations below, I suppose that each subject sees 50 recycled images
and 50 fresh ones, for a total of 100 images. Also, 10,000 subjects of each
of the three kinds are simulated. Summaries of averages scores are found and
graphed as histograms. [The simulation is written in R. I have used loops instead of defining functions (perhaps more elegant), hoping that non-R users can follow the logic.]

```
# Clueless
set.seed(725)
m = 10000;  n = 100;  s.c = numeric(m)
t = rep(c(-1,1), each=50)
for(i in 1:m) {
  x = sample(1:9, n, rep=T);  y = x-5
  z = t*y;  s.c[i]=mean(z) }
mean(s.c);  sd(s.c)
[1] -0.00221
[1] 0.2579402
summary(s.c)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.98000 -0.18000  0.00000 -0.00221  0.17000  0.97000
```

.

```
# Attentive
m = 10000;  n = 100;  s.a = numeric(m)
t = rep(c(-1,1), each=50)
for(i in 1:m) {
  x1 = sample(1:6, n/2, rep=T);  x2 = sample(4:9, n/2, rep=T)
  x = c(x1, x2);  y = x-5
  z = t*y; s.a[i]=mean(z) }
mean(s.a);  sd(s.a)
[1] 1.498803
[1] 0.1709028
summary(s.a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.850   1.380   1.500   1.499   1.620   2.170
```

.

```
# Perfect
m = 10000;  n = 100;  s.p = numeric(m)
t = rep(c(-1,1), each=50)
for(i in 1:m) {
  x1 = sample(1:2, n/2, rep=T);  x2 = sample(8:9, n/2, rep=T)
  x = c(x1, x2);  y = x-5
  z = t*y;  s.p[i]=mean(z) }
mean(s.p);  sd(s.p)
[1] 3.499701
[1] 0.04965146
summary(s.p)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.  
   3.26    3.47    3.50    3.50    3.53    3.68 


par(mfrow=c(1,3))
  hist(s.c, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Clueless")
  hist(s.a, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Mainly Attentive")
  hist(s.p, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Almost Perfect")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

With the slight modification made above, I think your scoring system would work
fine. It certainly distinguishes well among the three imaginary types of subjects
I considered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is OK.

Another option would be to recode answers for images that was actually not seen by participants before. In those cases you can recode 1 to 9, 2 to 8, 3 to 7 and so on (or just take $10-x$, where $x$ is original answer).

This would results in scores 1 to 9 for each question. If you prefer -4 to 4 scale, just subtract 5.

Answer (score 0):

**What an excellent and intriguing question!**

I would propose a different kind of transformation, though, that retains a little bit of more information.

What you basically have in your survey is a human (/ are a bunch of humans) trying to *predict* a *ground truth* (= "seen before" / "not seen before") that is known only to you and you alone. For all those predictions those humans have offered a *self-reported confidence level* (ranging from "sure" [1,9] to "not so sure" [4,6]).

I'm heavily into machine learning projects right now (and since if you show a problem to an apple tree it would always propose "apples, of course!" as the solution) I immediately thought of a **confusion matrix with a variable confidence level** as a possible approach.

**How would that work?**

1. Transformation / Feature Engineering
2. Building the Confusion Matrix
3. Scoring the Test

---

### 1. Transformation / Feature Engineering

**Assumptions:**

- We could assume that answers with a Likert Scale value from 1 to 4 predict a "0" and answers with a value from 6 to 9 predict a "1".
- We could also assume that there are the following confidence levels:

  - 4 and 6 — 25% confidence (not so sure)
  - 3 and 7 — 50% confidence (a bit sure)
  - 2 and 8 — 75% confidence (moderately sure)
  - 1 and 9 — 100% confidence (sure)
- We could also assume that an answer with a value of 5 can be treated as "N/A", as the participant was not sure at all about their answer.

Therefore we can construct a table from the answers like

> `RespondentID, QuestionID, GroundTruth, Prediction, Confidence
>   1702,1,1,1,0.75
>   1702,2,0,1,0.25
>   1702,3,1,1,0.75
>   1702,4,1,1,1.00
>   1702,5,0,1,0.50
>   1702,7,1,1,0.25
>   ...`

We also can calculate a `result` column with values being either 0 or 1 (i.e., was the answer correct?) from `GroundTruth` and `Prediction`.

This would look like this:

> `RespondentID, QuestionID, GroundTruth, Prediction, Confidence, Result
>   1702,1,1,1,0.75,1
>   1702,2,0,1,0.25,0
>   1702,3,1,1,0.75,1
>   1702,4,1,1,1.00,1
>   1702,5,0,1,0.50,0
>   1702,7,1,1,0.25,1
>   ...`

Now we can calculate: ***How good*** was our participant, actually?

---

### 2. Building the Confusion Matrix

A confusion matrix a fundamental tool in the evaluation of predictive systems. Your participants, for the purpose of this experiment, is such a system. So let's evaluate them! 
There are four central terms you have to know:

- **True Positive** - Has seen the picture before and answered correctly
- **True Negative** - Has not seen the picture before and answered correctly
- **False Positive** (False Alarm) - Has not seen the picture before and falsely remembered it
- **False Negative** (Miss) - Has seen the picture before, but could not remember

True Positive and True Negative are **good cases**, False Positive and False Negative are **bad cases**. With this information you can actually find out how good the participant performed on various metrics. For this purpose, I have created an Excel file with dummy data so you can play around with it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QXhnd6LLcHaEl6SjkwN0NvSVhVc3VhRTNVT0NxeXhPaE9v/view?usp=sharing

So, but how do we calculate a score?

---

### 3. Scoring the Test

You have already proposed a method: using the confidence as a multiplier. There is nothing wrong with it, buuuuut:

- Was this methodology clear from the beginning?
- Was it communicated clearly to the participants?
- What does "sure" / "not so sure" mean for every participant? Are the meanings homogenous?

What is more, you should ask yourself what you want to achieve with your methodology:

- Do you want to reward participants who are more confident? If yes, how much?
- Do you want to punish wrong answers? If yes, how severely?
- What do you want to do with participants who answered "5"?
- and many more...

I mean, after all you could score the **Matthews Correlation Coefficient** (MCC) of the participant's answers?!

But just for completeness' sake I have added a `points` column, so it now reads

> `RespondentID, QuestionID, GroundTruth, Prediction, Confidence, Result
>   1702,1,1,1,0.75,1,0.75
>   1702,2,0,1,0.25,0,0.00
>   1702,3,1,1,0.75,1,0.75
>   1702,4,1,1,1.00,1,1.00
>   1702,5,0,1,0.50,0,0.00
>   1702,7,1,1,0.25,1,0.25
>   ...`

---

All right, I have to go back to work. Hope I could give you some food for though. If you have any follow-up questions please do not hesitate to use the comment function.

Link to Excel file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4QXhnd6LLcHaEl6SjkwN0NvSVhVc3VhRTNVT0NxeXhPaE9v/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but rather an extensive comment.

- What are you after, what is your dependent variable, what is your design?
- You probably have not only correct and incorrect, but rather true positives, true negatives, false positives, and false negatives. This is more informative, and you may use measures such as [hit rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity), [d'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_index), [ROC curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic), etc.
- You loose information by combining accuracy and confidence into one measure. Making a combined model of both measures is much more complicated but will give you more information.
- Cognitive psychologist often have similar data (accuracy + confidence) and use models from [signal-detection](/questions/tagged/signal-detection) theory or multinomial processing tree models (e.g., Heck et al., 2018; Erdfelder et al., 2009).
- *Confidence* rather than *certainty* might be a better term for googling.

Heck, D. W., Erdfelder, E., & Kieslich, P. J. (2018). Generalized Processing Tree Models: Jointly Modeling Discrete and Continuous Variables. *Psychometrika*, Advance online publication. [doi:10.1007/s11336-018-9622-0](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11336-018-9622-0).
Erdfelder, E., Auer, T.-S., Hilbig, B. E., Aßfalg, A., Moshagen, M., & Nadarevic, L. (2009). Multinomial processing tree models. *Zeitschrift für Psychologie / Journal of Psychology*, *217*, 108–124. [doi:10.1027/0044-3409.217.3.108](https://doi.org/10.1027/0044-3409.217.3.108)